# Call the one function daily on specific time in Ionic Application

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I want to call the angularJS  function daily on specific time to send sms at background from my ionic application.I have googling on same but I am not getting any track to achieve this.

Is this possible with a Cordova Ionic based app, and how would I implement this to execute the necessary code if the app is closed or open at background?

Comment: sending SMS is easily achievable on the server. on client side you would require your up running in the background just because 1 sms per day, and this is not good practice

Comment: I want to send multiple sms to my all contacts and also download other data in my app on daily basis

Comment: you can download data when user starts the app, or when goes idle. as far as I know iOS won't let you to send SMS programatically, so you will need backend service for that anyways.

Comment: ok , thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Cordova Local-Notification Plugin to alert you everyday, the time you want. You can handle this notification in your program and trigger the process you want to run. You can't programmatically send SMS in iOS. You can try out some SMS gateways to send sms.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,I want send sms at background , Is this possible ?

Comment: in iOS, it is not possible to send sms without user intervention.

Comment: It is possible in android. This plugin may help you on sending sms. https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin